# Pandas Pivot-Table, Wrong Layout

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I'm dealing with rank-choice voting, so this gets messy. To put it simply...

**What I want**:

```
|Row Labels| Sum of Votes|
 ---------- -------------
 A                    100   # How many people chose this order. 100 people want A first
 ---------- -------------  <- These lines don't matter. Just to help visualize
   B                   25   # 25 people who want A first want B second.
     C                 10
     D                  3  
   C                   12
     B                  8
     D                 11  
 ---------- -------------
 B                    135
 ---------- -------------
   A                    5
     C                 40
     D
   C                  ...
     A                ...
     D
```

**My code:**

```py
pivot = pd.pivot_table(
    df, values=["Votes"], index=["1st", "2nd", "3rd"], aggfunc=np.sum
)
```

**Result:**

But the result looks like this:

```
1st  2nd  3rd  Votes
--------------------
 A     B    C     10  # Three get put on same row and 10 represents only C. 
            D      3  # This fine, but others should also have own row and sum.
       C    B      8    
            D     11
 B     A    C     40
            D     ..
       C    A     ..
            D
```

**Some further explanation**:

It's supposed to be a pivot table for rank-choice voting, with four candidates: A, B, C, D.

The top-level indent has the sum of people who chose A or B as their first choice. The second level indent represents how many people who had A as their first choice had B or C as their second choice (25 for B and 12 for C, of those who chose A first). etc.

Is it possible to do this pivot table layout with Pandas (this is the automated layout with Excel)?

**Sample of data (just using made up numbers.):**

```
idx  Votes  1st  2nd  3rd  4th
  0    25     C    A    D    B
  1    16     C    A    B    D
  2     9     C    D    A    B
etc..
```

Comment: Pls post a sample of your data

Comment: @gtomer, I added a sample of how my data looks just prior to creating the pivot-table.